# Signing PDF Document streamed from Byte Array

Tags: c#, database, adobe, arrays, outputstream

The specific error that I am getting from Adobe Acrobat and/or Reader

"The document could not be signed
 There was an error when attempting to commit this signature.  The document was not saved.
 This file must be saved with a full save."

The PDF that I am trying to sign is being created from byte array displaying into an IFrame from the binary data that is stored in a database.

```
            byte[] stream = (from m in db.pdf_store
                             where m.pdf_id == uid
                             select m.pdf_binary).First().ToArray();
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "Inline");
            Response.OutputStream.Write(stream, 0, stream.Length);
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
```

This code works fine to display the PDF as well as show the Signature fields in Internet Explorer.  I can click on the signature box, use a signature pad to sign the document, but when I click accept I receive the error above.

I believe this may have something to do with the PDF not being an actual file.  Any suggestions or help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the Issue.  I was using Itextsharp to create modify the PDF.  I found I had to use append mode to keep the User Rights in tack.  I also found that in order to use append mode for Itextsharp when creating a byte array, you must read it in using ToArray instead of GetBuffer.